# Resteasy - Override Method with generics

Tags: java, generics, overriding, resteasy

Right now i am working with resteasy. I have build a little Rest Application with the following struktur:
Controller Class:

```
@PATH("/rest")
public abstract class Controller<T>
{
  @POST
  public Response post(T ressource){[..]}

  @PUT
  public Response put(T ressource){[..]}

  @DELETE
  @Path("/{id}")
  public Response delete(@PathParam(value = "id") int id)

  @GET
  public Response get(){[..]}
}
```

ConrollerA Class (This is only an Example):

```
PATH("/rest/A")
public class ControllerA extends Controller<RessourceA>
{
  @Override
  public Response post(RessourceA ressource){[..]}

  [..]

  @Override
  public Response get(){[..]}
}
```

I start the server with jetty right now and everytime i make a POST Request to "/rest/A", the Server tells me, that there is no such a method but if i make a GET Requst to the Path it all works.
Is there a Problem with Jetty or Java if i override a Method with generic typs?

If i write the "@POST" annotation above the method it works, but i do not want this kind of solution. Do i have to make some settings in the web.xml or is the problem with java?